# Join attributes by "locations"

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I got a DXF file with some height data which I can easly open in QGIS, the problem is when I import it to QGIS is that the "float" is separated from it's Integer. Instead of one point with 4.8 is there two points one with 4 and one with 8. And those points that is 5.0 does not have its "float" and is just "5". Like this:

[image: Visualizing the data]

Is there any tool in QGIS that I can use to combine the float and integer? The "float" is approximativ 1.7m south east of the integer.

Comment: There's the nearest neighbor join plugin, but I don't think it will distinguish between float points and integer points. So a point pair with values 3 and 7 will combine as 3,7 and 7,3. It looks like the float is always a offset by the same distance in the same direction, so maybe you can use the `wedge_buffer()` function with the `intersects()` function to figure out which points are floats and which are integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comment!

To solve this problem, I first used the NNJoin plugin and joined all nearest neighbor. The "problem" is that also the points without the float got a joined value, to solve this I used the wedge buffer algoritm where I "targeted" the integer part (NW). 
[image: Img1]
Now I used `select by location` and selected all "integer parts" so in the picture above the `5` close to `2` was selected but not the single `5` bellow. Then I updated the selected features of that layer and created a new column "not_int" and set it to 1.

Now I wanted to remove all "float" points so then I created a new wedged buffer (SE) and `select by location` with the new buffer. Then I deleted all selected rows.

Finally I updated the remaining point with this case statement `CASE WHEN not_int THEN  to_real("Height" +'.'+ "join_Height") ELSE to_real("Height") END`

With this result:
[image: img2]